# Measure execution time of web worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, web-worker

I would like to measure execution time of a webworker that computes factorization. The webworker is messaging live results and once computations are terminated, the webworker sends a 'finished' message. I used promise to do this in my react app.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const measureTimeStart = performance.now();
  (async () => {
    try {
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('facto.js', import.meta.url));
        worker.postMessage(number);
        worker.onmessage = message => { //streaming live results 
          const { facto, status } = message.data;
          setResults({ ...facto }); //adding them to React state
          if (status === 'finished') {
            resolve();
            worker.terminate();
          };
        };
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })();
  const measureTimeEnd = performance.now();
  setExecutionTime(Math.round((measureTimeEnd - measureTimeStart) * 1000) / 1000 + ' ms');
}, [number]); //number to factorize
```

However, `performance.now()` doesn't wait that the promise resolves and consequently gives me arbitrary timing. Why? thanks.

Comment: Your code does not await the self execution function you created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  runWebWorker()
}, [number])

async function runWebWorker() {
  const start = performance.now()
  await ...
  const end = performance.now()
}
```

Alternatively, have your worker send performance data, which is more measurable and excludes the `postMessage` queue latency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the promise to resolve before measuring the time. Either with `finally` or `then`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const measureTimeStart = performance.now();
  (async () => {
    try {
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        const worker = new Worker(new URL('facto.js', import.meta.url));
        worker.postMessage(number);
        worker.onmessage = message => { //streaming live results 
          const { facto, status } = message.data;
          setResults({ ...facto }); //adding them to React state
          if (status === 'finished') {
            resolve();
            worker.terminate();
          };
        };
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })().finally(() => {
    const measureTimeEnd = performance.now();
    setExecutionTime(Math.round((measureTimeEnd - measureTimeStart) * 1000) / 1000 + ' ms');
  });
  
}, [number]); //number to factorize
```

Comment: I didn't accept it because @AnthumChris answer seems cleaner but I upvoted

Comment: Im happy if you found your answer